# AccessControlException when starting embedded Tomcat from Java Webstart

Tags: java, security, tomcat, java-web-start

For our [Kunagi](http://kunagi.org) Java web application we have a signed `kunagi.jar` file which contains our classes together with classes from embedded Tomcat 6. This runs perfectly when calling `java -jar kunagi.jar`.

But when starting it with Java WebStart, I get an exception while embedded Tomcat is starting:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.deploy)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:393)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1529)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:291)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1018)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2444)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2687)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetPublicIdRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    ... 33 more
```

Of course `kunagi.jar` is signed, otherwise it wouldn't even start. It seams Java WebStart enables Java Security globally, which somehow embedded Tomcat "inherits" and fails to initialize.

Here is the JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://kunagi.org/webstart" href="kunagi.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Kunagi</title>
        <vendor>Kunagi Team</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://kunagi.org"/>
        <description>SCRUM Tool</description>
        <description kind="short">SCRUM Tool</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="kunagi.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc name="Kunagi" main-class="katokorbo.Katokorbo"/>
    <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

Is there a way to disable security checks for Tomcat inside of Java WebStart? Or how can I configure embedded Tomcat to permit access to `org.apache.catalina...`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved my problem as follows:

Disable security manager after WebStart started my application. First line in my `main()` method:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

Tell Tomcat to use the default class loader:

```
context.setLoader(new WebappLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()));
```

Now Tomcat runs within WebStart :-D

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat implements Security Manager access rules in various places. The associated policy definitions are found in tomcat/conf/catalina.policy.

It is not be a bug in Tomcat if a) the Security Manager is turned on, and b) the required policy file is not applied.

Of course Tomcat contains code in various packages, and of course it would be normal for it to use classes from those packages.

UPDATE: I don't have a problem running your JNLP application in my sandbox. Tomcat starts up successfully, with some exceptions that are unrelated to the one you describe.  I would try removing any previously downloaded files & try to clear any certs from your cache.

I'd also suggest an upgrade to a recent version of Tomcat 6.0.

Comment: But perhaps it is a bug, that Tomcat automaticaly turns security manager on, when started via WebStart? Shouldn't there be a separate switch?

Comment: WebStart runs with SecurityManager. Then Tomcat requires permissions to run properly. The Tomcat code is ready to run with SecurityManager thanks to PrivilegedAction usage.

Comment: So it could be a bug in WebStart? I have granted all-permissions to my WebStart application, but obviously it denies access to Tomcat classes.

Comment: As stated elsewhere, Tomcat doesn't turn the SecurityManager on.

Comment: @Witek: I think the problem is one of two things: 1) you didn't configure your "all permissions" properly or 2) WebStart simply doesn't allow "all permissions" but only a strict subset of them. You might want to do a lot more reading about WebStart. Tomcat itself runs quite well under a SecurityManager -- as long as the proper policy has been applied.

Answer (score 3):

@Witek: Tomcat doesn't turn the SecurityManager on: the JVM must be started with a SecurityManager enabled and a policy file in place. Tomcat launches long after the SecurityManager is in place.

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be to digitally sign the jars that ask for a permission that requires trust.  Anything which is unsigned and requires no trust will need to be moved to an extension JNLP.

Comment: There is only one jar (kunagi.jar). It contains Kunagi classes and all required Tomcat classes. It is signed.

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP file?  Post it as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat appears to have used its permissions to modify global state (here the `package.access` security property). Signed jars may be run in processes shared by untrusted code. You don't really want to mix the two more than necessary. So it doesn't look as if Tomcat, in the from it is being used here, is appropriate for WebStart.

(The Oracle JRE does have a security checking trace feature - `-Djava.security.debug=all`, IIRC).

Comment: What evidence is there that Tomcat has used its permissions to modify global state?

Comment: @Pidster `java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.deploy` I don't remember that being package having access restricted in the JRE. It's also in the source code.

Comment: If the SecurityManager is turned on, Tomcat performs extra access control checks in various bits of its code - that's all that's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.deploy)

Whenever you get an `AccessControlException`, the part in brackets is the permission that you need to grant in your .policy file, or, as you are using JWS, in the deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, this seems like a bug in Tomcat, and you should probably report it. It shouldn't be trying to fetch the methods of a class in another package, since that will always fail under a security manager.

Until such time as the bug can be fixed, however, can't you avoid having the "`WebRuleSet`" thingie called? I don't know what it actually is, but it seems like something that would be called because of your Tomcat configuration. Is it not something that you can remove from the config?

Comment: What would make you claim that?

Comment: You claimed there was a bug in Tomcat. I don't believe you've shown any evidence to support that.  Tomcat is functioning as expected.

Comment: Well, as I did write, "It shouldn't be trying to fetch the methods of a class in another package, since that will always fail under a security manager", and Tomcat is supposed to be able to run under a security manager.

Comment: And that statement is wrong.  How many packages do you think that Tomcat contains? Do you think that the whole of Tomcat's code is in a single package?
If your statement is accurate, how should Tomcat access the classes in, for example, the package javax.servlet?

Comment: Are you interpreting me as saying that methods in other packages cannot be called? What I'm saying is that classes in other packages cannot be introspected. To qualify the statement, the methods of a class cannot be introspected unless the caller's ClassLoader is an ancestor of the introspected class' ClassLoader, or the SecurityManager explicitly allows it. Therefore, if Tomcat is supposed to work under a SecurityManager (which it is), it shouldn't be introspecting potentially foreign classes without guarding for a SecurityException.

Comment: I disagree that there is a bug in Tomcat.  Why should Tomcat catch an AccessControlException?

It's correct that it throws the AccessControlException, so either 

a) in it's normal form Tomcat doesn't start up - because the permissions in conf/catalina.policy are incorrect or, 

b) in embedded form, the code around Tomcat can make a decision about how to handle the failure.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your policy file. for example, you'd security issue when you deploy admin war, you will have to edit catalina.policy located in tomcat conf directory to have low entry like below to solve this issue.

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/admin/-" {
                permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```