# Permission to access classes in Java WebStart

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I have created a .jar file which contains my classes together with classes which I have extracted from multiple Apache Tomcat jars. Then I have signed the jar and created a JNLP file with `<security><all-permissions/>`.

But when running my application, WebStart denies access to classes from my jar:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.deploy)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:393)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1529)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:291)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1018)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2444)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2687)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetPublicIdRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    ... 33 more
```

Is this a bug in WebStart or why do I get this security exception?

Comment: Tomcat adds to the package.access security property, which isn't really an appropriate thing to be doing in WebStart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the security manager by calling:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

I have used this from a Java Web Start application to gain complete control but the application needs to be signed and have the

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

as you stated correctly.

Comment: Please post your answer also here, to get a bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831063/accesscontrolexception-when-starting-embedded-tomcat-from-java-webstart

Comment: Never do that in signed code! You'll, er, remove the security manager from whatever process happens to be running.

Comment: What's the problem with that? With <all-permissions> the application already has access to all users data.

Comment: I agree with Witek. I have used this approach in cases were I wanted full control of the VM and setting all-permissions did not do it.

Comment: I agree with Tom.  A better way is to implement a ***custom*** security manager that provides extended (not full) access only to particular classes (yours).

Comment: @Witek The jar may be used in a process that is shared with untrusted code.

Comment: I think it depend on the type of application. If the application is an internal which isn't going to be used by customer the solution with a null security manager is OK, but if this is a commercial product or something that is going to be launched from a public web page I agree with Tom.

Comment: @ChristianDamsgaard You're then relying on perimeter security, and I can't imagine there's many significantly sized networks that don't have a "persistent threat". In an applet, on a shared-JVM JNLP container, etc., then the user is completely open to any site they happen to browse.

Comment: @Tom - could you please elaborate a little on the shared JVM JNLP container - I tried to Google the concept but I din't not find any relevant information on it. If multiple JNLP application shares the same JVM instance I see a serious problem, but for the single in-house JNLP based application setting the security manager to null - Not a really a problem in opinion.